# How to get the output of a shell function without forking a sub shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have the following functions.

```
hello () {
        echo "Hello"
}
func () {
        hello
        echo "world"
}
```

If I don't want the output of the hello function to be printed but want to do something with it, I want to capture the output in some variable, Is the only possible way is to fork a subshell like below? Is it not an unnecessary creation of a new child process? Can this be optimized?

```
func () {
        local Var=$(hello)
        echo "${Var/e/E} world"
}
```

Comment: It may be a creation of a subshell, but why is it a problem?  Are you sure you're not optimizing prematurely?

Comment: @evilotto It may be a problem if function has side effects besides outputting to stdout: for example, changing variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ugly solution is to temporarily replace `echo` so that it sets a global variable, which you can access from your function:

```
func () {
  echo () {
    result="$@"
  }
  result=
  hello
  unset -f echo
  echo "Result is $result"
}
```

I agree it's nasty, but avoids the subshell.

Comment: I was also thinking on similar lines. I can replace all echo with Echo which does something like this. Will this make the shell functions faster?

Answer (score 3):

How about using a file descriptor and a Bash here string?

```
hello () {
    exec 3<<<"Hello"
}

func () {
    local Var
    exec 3>&-
    hello && read Var <&3
    echo "${Var/e/E} world"
    exec 3>&-
}

func
```

Comment: Bash cryptics are practically endless,so4the~99% of us who even as long-time Bash coders NOT know-else-memomorize 100% of Bash docs, IN ENGLISH,"recode called fn so all its output is to a file-descriptor OTHER than stdout then manipulate that"(advanced!),per relevant OFFICIAL URLs FOR *ADVANCED* Bash ops  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec & http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors tho no find defined there quote(>&-) tho I do  at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#CFD

Comment: --Advanced! But is there a way (put in another answer here) to do this as the asker apparently asked(I really want,too): WITHOUT having to recode the function being called(so say in this case function remains hello(){ echo "Hello" })? -but still NOT creating a sub-shell(so then allowing the fn to do visible environment side-effects&more benefits),as called fn's stdout still redirected to this other file-descriptor. I made attempts such as my (internal)ID N6ZPBM where quote(exec hello 1>&3) (see my last cmt for official defs of these ops),but sadly these just give quote(3: Bad file descriptor).

Answer (score 3):

You can make the caller pass in a variable name to hold the output value and then create a global variable with that name inside the function, like this:

```
myfunc() { declare -g $1="hello"; }
```

Then call it as:

```
myfunc mystring
echo "$mystring world" # gives "hello world"
```

So, your functions can be re-written as:

```
hello() {
    declare -g $1="Hello"
}

func() {
    hello Var
    echo "${Var/e/E} world"
}
```

The only limitation is that variables used for holding the output values can't be local.

---

Related post which talks about using namerefs:

- [How to return an array in bash without using globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971213/6862601)

Answer (score 2):

Not a bash answer: At least one shell, *ksh* optimises command substitution `$( ... )` to *not* spawn a subshell for builtin commands.  This can be useful when your script tends to perform a lot of these.

Comment: bash appears to do the same

Comment: @LaurenceRenshaw  In bash 4.4.12(1) on linux, `echo $(echo foo)` calls clone(), according to strace.  That makes me think it *does* spawn a subshell.  Do you have evidence that it doesn't?

Comment: It is a child process, but not a full sub-shell. The child does not call `exec()`, so does not incur the full overhead of a sub-shell, but it is still a separate process.

Comment: @AndrewVickers  The ksh93 shell does not always fork for `$( ... )`, so no new process is created.

Comment: @Hank. Good to know for ksh, but apparently not the case for bash.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option of modifying the `hello()` function? If so, then give it an option to store the result in a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
  local text="hello"

  if [ ${#1} -ne 0 ]; then
    eval "${1}='${text}'"
  else
    echo "${text}"
  fi
}

func () {
  local var     # Scope extends to called functions.
  hello var
  echo "${var} world"
}
```

And a more compact version of `hello()`:

```
hello() {
  local text="hello"
  [ ${#1} -ne 0 ]  && eval "${1}='${text}'" || echo "${text}"
}
```

Comment: Actually, why even bother with `-v`. If there is a parameter, we can assume it is the variable name.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: Fantastic! This works in a primitive BusyBox interpreter too.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't literally answer the question, but it is a viable alternate approach for some use cases...

This is sort of a spin off from @Andrew Vickers, in that you can lean on `eval`.

Rather than define a function, define what I'll call a "macro" (the C equivalent):

```
MACRO="local \$var=\"\$val world\""

func()
{ 
    local var="result"; local val="hello"; eval $MACRO; 
    echo $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Redirect the stdout of the function to the FD of the write end of an "automatic" pipe. Then, after the (non-forking) call, ...
2. Read the FD of the read end of the same pipe.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This code prints 'var=2, out=hello' meaning var was set and the stdout got captured
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502981/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-shell-function-without-forking-a-sub-shell

main(){
  local -i var=1             # Set value
  local -i pipe_write=0 pipe_read=0  # Just defensive programming
  create_pipe                # Get 2 pipe automatic fd, see function below

  # HERE IS THE CALL
  callee >&"$pipe_write"     # Run function, see below

  exec {pipe_write}>&-       # Close fd of the pipe writer end (to make cat returns)
  local out=$(cat <&"$pipe_read")  # Grab stdout of callee
  exec {pipe_read}>&-        # Just defensive programming
  echo "var=$var, out=$out"  # Show result
}

callee(){
  var=2       # Set an outer scope value
  echo hello  # Print some output
}

create_pipe(){
  : 'From: https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo
    Return: pipe_write and pipe_read fd => to outer scope
  '
  exec 2> /dev/null  # Avoid job control print like [1] 1030612
  tail -f /dev/null | tail -f /dev/null &
  exec 2>&1

  # Save the process ids
  local -i pid2=$!
  local -i pid1=$(jobs -p %+)

  # Hijack the pipe's file descriptors using procfs
  exec {pipe_write}>/proc/"$pid1"/fd/1
  # -- Read
  exec {pipe_read}</proc/"$pid2"/fd/0
  
  disown "$pid2"; kill "$pid1" "$pid2"
}

main
```

---

Note that it would be much shorter code using an automatic normal fd as follows:

```bash
exec {fd}<> <(:)
```

instead of using the `create_pipe` function as this code does (copying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/633185)). But then the reading FD line used here like:

```bash
local out=$(cat <&"$fd")
```

would block. And it would be necessary to try reading with a timeout like the following:

```bash
local out=''
while read -r -t 0.001 -u "${fd}" line; do
  out+="$line"$'\n'
done
```

But I try to avoid arbitrary `sleeps` or `timeouts` if possible.\
Here the closing of the FD of write end of the pipe makes the read `cat` line returns at the end of content (magically from my poor knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the buildin mapfile:

```
hello > foo     # put the output of hello into file 'foo'
mapfile Var < foo # put the content of file foo in variable Var
```

No fork subshell happens here (we checked with strace).

Of course, instead, you have an access (write then read) to the file-system, which may be RAM only if /tmp, and file-cache only in most usecases.