# How to drop args and pass remain down in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to implement this function, it will drop the first elem of the shell args $@, and pass the remain args to another function.
If I pass 3 elems: "1 2", "2 3", "3 4"
it will drop "1 2", and pass 2 elems: "2 3" and "3 4" to another function, that function will receive two params: "2 3" and "3 4".

I don't know how to do this, it seems once I convert it to string, I can never convert it back correctly?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Example

```
#!/bin/bash
shift
func "$@"
```

Documentation

```
$ help shift
shift: shift [n]
    The positional parameters from $N+1 ... are renamed to $1 ...  If N is
    not given, it is assumed to be 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach which doesn't use `shift` and therefore keeps your original `$@` in tact.

First, let's create a `bash` array from `$@`:

```
args=("$@")
```

Now, let's remove the first element:

```
unset args[0]
```

We can now call another script using all but the first argument:

```
other_script "${args[@]}"
```

#### Specific Example

Let's create a `bash` array:

```
$ args=( "1 2" "2 3" "3 4" )
```

Let's verify that we have the array we expect:

```
$ declare -p args
declare -a args='([0]="1 2" [1]="2 3" [2]="3 4")'
```

Now, let's remove the first element:

```
$ unset args[0]
```

Let's verify that the first argument has been removed:

```
$ declare -p args
declare -a args='([1]="2 3" [2]="3 4")'
```

Comment: Thanks, cool.  By the way, how do you return an array from a function? I always get "2" "3" "3" "4", but not "2 3" "3 4".

Comment: @user1453345 Yes, that is what you get: _shell functions return strings_.   There is no _direct_ way to return an array.   The simplest _indirect_ method, if the function is running in the current shell not a subshell, is to have it create a _global_ array which you can then access.   If globals are not satisfactory, some other work-arounds are discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582763/how-to-return-an-array-in-bash-without-using-globals).

Answer (score 0):

Use [shift](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/shift) command. For e.g. if to my script (with below excerpt) i pass `1 2 3` as positional parameters:

```
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift   
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
Output:
arg1= 1 arg2=2  arg3=3 
arg1= 2 arg2=3  arg3= 
arg1= 3 arg2=   arg3=
```