# Circular name reference

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function contains() {
  local -n array=$1
  local value=$2
  for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    [ "$item" = "$value" ] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}

array=(a "b c" "d")
value="b c"

contains array value
```

Running it I get this error:

```
***: line 6: warning: array: circular name reference
```

What does this mean? How to fix this?

Comment: rename `array=(a "b c" "d")` to `somethingelse=(a "b c" "d")`

Comment: @amdixon yes, this helps, but wasn't `local -n array=$1` supposed to work?

Comment: When you execute `contains array value`, the first line of the function becomes `local -n array=array`. See the circular reference?

Comment: See the exact issue in BashFAQ/048, by the way: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#line-120.

Comment: @4ae1e1 that would be a good answer

Comment: @amdixon Sure, I'll convert that to an answer (usually I'm too lazy to write answers...).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's focus on the first line of the function `contains`:

```
local -n array=$1
```

When one executes

```
contains array value
```

`$1` is set to `array`, so the `local` command, after expansions, becomes

```
local -n array=array
```

where a circular reference is immediately obvious.

This is a known issue without a perfect solution (see ["The problem with bash's name references"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#line-120) in BashFAQ/048). I would suggest what's suggested there:

> [T]here is no safe name we can give to the name reference. If the caller's variable happens to have the same name, we're screwed.
>
> ...
>
> Now, despite these shortcomings, the `declare -n` feature is a step in the right direction. But you must be careful to select a name that the caller won't use (which means you need some control over the caller, if only to say "don't use variables that begin with `_my_pkg`"), and you must reject unsafe inputs.