# Bash read file line by line and store into array

Tags: bash

Trying figure out how to read txt file line by line and store it into an array:
How to modify IFS command to accept an array?

```
index=0;
while IFS= read -r line; do
#echo "$line"


#let index=index+1
#echo "$index"
done < myFile.txt

echo $line[0]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the `readarray` command?

Comment: If `readarray` is not available (i.e bash 3.x), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475261/need-alternative-to-readarray-mapfile-for-script-on-older-version-of-bash