# Replacement of "readarray -d / -t" (for splitting path) on older bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, path

I need to run a script that uses `readarray -d / -t` to split filepaths into arrays, but the `readarray` of the targeted system doesn't support the `-d` option (bash version 4.2.46)

As I don't know the exact behaviour of `readarray -d / -t`, it is difficult for me to write a workaround for it.
It doesn't **seem** possible to replace it with `IFS=/ read -a` because filenames containing control characters will break it, as shown here:

```sh
IFS=/ read -a arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
declare -p arr
# OUTPUT: declare -a arr='([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="fravadona")'
```

So, my first question is, what's the expected result of:

```sh
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona)
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/)
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
```

And lastly, does the following code emulates `readline -d / -t` correctly?

```sh
filepath=/home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath

unset arr; declare -a arr

prefix="${filepath%%/*}"
suffix="${filepath#*/}"

until [ "X$prefix" == "X$suffix" ]
do
    arr+=( "$prefix" )
    prefix="${suffix%%/*}"
    suffix="${suffix#*/}"
done

arr+=( "$prefix" )
```

Comment: `readarray` reads all input and produces one array. `read` reads a single line at a time producing an array for each. I notice you have a directory that's a non-printable character. Is this malware?

Comment: @jordanm: That's only an example that breaks a possible `IFS=/ read -a' workaround.

Comment: `what's the expected result of:` sooo, why don't you run it and see? `readarray` is internal to bash, the expected output is what bash wants it to be, documentation is basically documentation of code, not specification.

Comment: @KamilCuk: `readarray -d / arr <<< /home/KamilCuk` `-bash: readarray: -d: invalid option`. As you can see, it doesn't work on the target system ;-)

Comment: Och, so you mean you do not have bash5 available at hand? Try it out online. https://replit.com/ has bash Also, use docker, docker is always handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this would achieve what you expected :

```
filepath=/home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath
IFS=/ read -d "" -r -a arr < <(printf "%s" "$filepath")
declare -p arr
```

Comment: Thank you Philippe. Is there any character in a filepath that could break this workaround?

Comment: No character in a filepath can break this workaround.

Comment: This workaround works fine on bash 3.2.57 (macOS)

Comment: Good to know ! I tested only on bash 4.2

Answer (score 1):

> What is the exact behaviour of bash "readarray -d / -t"?

Read all input. Split it on `/`. Remove `/`. Assign to array.

> what's the expected result of:

The following script:

```
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona)
declare -p arr
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/)
declare -p arr
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
declare -p arr
```

outputs:

```
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]=$'fravadona\n')
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="fravadona" [3]=$'\n')
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="fravadona" [3]=$'\n' [4]=$'underneath\n')
```

> does the following code emulates readline -d / -t correctly?

Your code does not read from stdin, so it does not emulate `readline`. It seems you assume the input is stored in some variable.

The following code:

```
f() {
    IFS= read -d '' -r filepath
    arr=()

    prefix="${filepath%%/*}"
    suffix="${filepath#*/}"

    until [ "X$prefix" == "X$suffix" ]
    do
        arr+=( "$prefix" )
        prefix="${suffix%%/*}"
        suffix="${suffix#*/}"
    done

    arr+=( "$prefix" )
}
f < <(echo /home/fravadona)
declare -p arr
f < <(echo /home/fravadona/)
declare -p arr
f < <(echo /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
declare -p arr
```

outputs:

```
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]=$'fravadona\n')
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="fravadona" [3]=$'\n')
declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="fravadona" [3]=$'\n' [4]=$'underneath\n')
```

So it's the same, so the answer after some adjustments would be yes.

It's odd that you use `[ X` trick nawadays - the old bugs are long gone, and anyway `==` is non-standard for `[`.. In bash, just use `[[ "$prefix" == "$suffix" ]]`

Related: [Need alternative to readarray/mapfile for script on older version of Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475261/need-alternative-to-readarray-mapfile-for-script-on-older-version-of-bash) . I would go with zero bytes, something like:

```
f() {
   arr=();
   while IFS= read -d '' -r elem || [[ -n "$elem" ]]; do
         arr+=("$elem")
   done < <(
         tr '/' '\0'
   )
}
```

Comment: A great thank you KamilCuk; you explained well a few things that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't [seem] possible to replace it with `IFS=/ read -a` because filenames containing control characters will break it,

Specifically, filenames containing newlines will break it.  Other control characters should not be an issue.

> So, my first question is, what's the expected result of:
>
> ```
> readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona)
> readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/)
> readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
> ```

They are equivalent to, respectively,

```sh
arr=('' home $'fravadona\n')
arr=('' home fravadona $'\n')
arr=('' home fravadona $'\n' $'underneath\n' )
```

Note that each array has an empty first element corresponding to the first "line", with the trailing delimiter removed.

And note in particular that the last element of every result contains a trailing newline.  This is because `echo` ends its output with one by default, and you are instructing `readarray` to use a different line delimiter.

You might, then, also be interested in these ...

```
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo -n /home/fravadona)
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo -n /home/fravadona/)
readarray -d / -t arr < <(echo -n /home/fravadona/$'\n'/underneath)
```

... which produce the same results as ...

```sh
arr=('' home fravadona)
arr=('' home fravadona)
arr=('' home fravadona $'\n' underneath)
```

> And lastly, does the following code emulates readline -d / -t
> correctly?
>
> ```
> unset arr; declare -a arr
>
> prefix="${filepath%%/*}"
> suffix="${filepath#*/}"
>
> until [ "X$prefix" == "X$suffix" ]
> do
>     arr+=( "$prefix" )
>     prefix="${suffix%%/*}"
>     suffix="${suffix#*/}"
> done
>
> arr+=( "$prefix" )
> ```

No, it does not, it least because the condition `[ "X$prefix" == "X$suffix" ]` is wrong.  For example, if `$filepath` is `foo/foo` then no iterations of the loop will be performed, and the final value of `arr` will contain only one element, not two.  Or if `$filepath` is `/foo/bar/bar` then the end result has only two elements, not three.

This would be better:

```
unset arr
declare -a arr

case $filepath in
*/) suffix=$filepath;;
*) suffix=${filepath}/;;
esac

while [[ -n "$suffix" ]]; do
  arr+=(${suffix%%/*})
  suffix=${suffix#*/}
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much John, for the explanations and the error in my code :-)