# How to return multiple arrays with function

Tags: bash

I wrote a function which returns an array:

```
create(){
   my_list=("a" "b" "c")
   echo "${my_list[@]}"
}

result=$(create)
for var in result
do
    echo $var
done
```

Now, I'd like to extend it in order to return multiple arrays.
For example, I'd like to write something like that:

```
create(){
    my1=("1" "2")
    my2=("3","4")
    my3=("5","6")
     echo "${my1[@]} ${my3[@]} ${my3[@]}"
}
```

and I'd like to get each of the returned arrays:

```
 res1= ...
 res2= ...
 res3= ...
```

Anyone could suggest me a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just maintain a variable in global context, returning arrays is not the best of ways to design your code

Comment: If you can let us know your requirement, there are sure better ways to do this

Comment: Use a real programming language.

Comment: Technically, you can't even return a *single* array; you can *output* the *elements* of one or more arrays.

Comment: Try setting `my_list=("a b" "c d" "e f")` inside `create` and see what happens.

Comment: @Inian. I'm newbie. Could you provide me an example?

Comment: @Inian I have a file to read. Each line has two values and I want to store the first value of each line in the first array, the second value of each line in the second array. I want to do this with a function.

Comment: @chepner And then, how can I assign them to 3 variables?

Comment: See [How to return an array in bash without using globals?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10582763/4154375).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read with a `while` loop.

```
while read -r val1 val2; do
    arr1+=("$val1")
    arr2+=("$val2")
done < file.txt
```

---

There is no such thing as an array *value* in `bash`; you cannot use arrays the way you are attempting in your question. Consider this result:

```
create(){
   my_list=("a 1" "b 2" "c 3")
   echo "${my_list[@]}"
}

result=$(create)
for var in $result
do
    echo $var
done
```

This produces

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

not

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```