# How to list only name of all subfolders under specific folder into a variable using linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder with path `./Ur/postProcessing/forces`, and it includes two sub_folders name `0` and `100`, now I want to list the name of these two sub_folders into a variable, like `time=(0 100)`.

My code is

```
dirs=(./Ur/postProcessing/forces/*/)

timeDirs=$(for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
           do
               echo "$dir"
           done)

echo "$timeDirs"
```

And I get the following results:

```
./Ur/postProcessing/forcs/0/
./Ur/postProcessing/forces/100/
```

How can I get (0 100) as a variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your scripts:

```sh
# change directory
cd ./Ur/postProcessing/forces/

# read all sub-directories in shell array dirs
dirs=(*/)

# check content of dirs
declare -p dirs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

get_times()( # sub-shell so don't need to cd back nor use local
    if cd "$1"; then

        # collect directories
        dirs=(*/)

        # strip trailing slashes and display
        echo "${dirs[@]%/}"
    fi
)

dir="./Ur/postProcessing/forces"

# assign into simple variable
timeStr="($(get_times "$dir"))"

# or assign into array
# (only works if get_times output is whitespace-delimited)
timeList=($(get_times "$dir"))
```

To return a real array, see: [How to return an array in bash without using globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10582763/10971581)